# Can't find my Pi on my home internet network by its hostname

Tags: networking, ethernet, pi-zero

I've got a Raspberry Pi Zero V1.2 that is plugged into a powered USB hub that in turn is plugged into my router via Ethernet cable. ([Basically like this](https://cdn.instructables.com/FW8/LBXA/IHKYJTVO/FW8LBXAIHKYJTVO.LARGE.jpg).)

On my desktop computer, running Arch Linux, when I try running `ssh pi@raspberrypi` to connect to the Pi, I get this error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Name or service not known`.

On the Pi, when I run `hostname` or `cat /etc/hostname`, the output is `raspberrypi`.

And here's the output of `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

On my Arch Linux computer, I can connect to the Pi Zero using its IP address on my network by running `ssh pi@192.168.1.7`.

What must I do to SSH into my Pi using its hostname too?

**update**

The output of `cat /etc/hosts` on my Arch machine is this...

```
# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.
```

Comment: Can you get to the Pi via ssh pi@raspberrypi.local? Is the Arch box running Avahi - if not load that onto the Arch box.  Does you router have a setting for the domain - if so check that is set to local.

Comment: Running `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` on my Arch Linux computer gets the same error. I've got the `avahi` package already installed on my Arch Linux. I'm not sure exactly what you mean about my router. But when I navigate to 192.168.1.1 in my browser and log into the router, then click "Attached devices" I see a table showing the Pi's IP address, device name and MAC address,

Comment: the quick and dirty method is to add an entry to the /etc./hosts file on the arch box for the pi.

Comment: or create an ssh config file on arch an use the server alias to call it by name

Comment: It sounds like the Arch Linux box is not "playing ball". If your router's table of DHCP leases contains a valid correct entry, and Arch is configured to check the router for DNS, it should work. Can you ssh from your RPi to the Arch box?

Comment: My router lists what I believe to be my Arch Linux at 192.168.1.4, with Device name "--". When I ssh into my Pi and then run `ssh 192.168.1.4`, I get this error: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.4 port 22: Connection refused`.

Comment: Do you have mDNS avahi-daemon installed on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @JohnS `avahi-daemon` is already installed on the Pi if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The Pi supports mDNS (multicast DNS).  This only works if the client *also* supports mDNS.  Basically instead of having to use a real DNS server or the /etc/hosts file to resolve the host name to an IP address, it does a broadcast query to say "who is raspberrypi.local" to all hosts on the LOCAL subnet (it will not cross a router boundary).  The host whose name is 'raspberrypi' will answer saying "I am raspberrypi and my IP address is xx.xx.xx.xx".  But if your Arch Linux doesn't have support for mDNS, this wont work.  mDNS uses broadcast messages which are not propagated across subsets.

Comment: How do I see if both my Pi and Arch have mDNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure your hostname files are setup correctly on BOTH ends:**

Pi `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

Arch (SSH Client) `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

[Pi WLAN/LAN IP] raspberrypi
```

Your Pi is likely to be 192.168.0.[something] or 10.0.1.[something]

This is only particularly useful if you have a [static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os) for your Pi.

**What I recommend instead of Hostnames for SSH...**

Is using the `~/.ssh/config` file:

In the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
host RasPi
    user pi
    hostname 192.168.0.[Pi IP]
```

This will be more useful for the purpose of SSH, and it much more useful (in my opinion) when you start to do more fancy things with SSH (Proxy jump, Port Forward, Local/External IP matching)

**Another thing that I have seen:**

Some people recommend using Bonjour for Hostname resolution.
So you can look into that if you want Hostname resolution on WLAN/LAN.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Updated my question to include output of `cat /etc/hosts` on my Arch machine. Will this affect how I implement your proposed solution?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been a little unclear. The suggested Pi and SSH client files should be the /etc/hosts files, not the /etc/hostname files. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Actually your answer worked. I went with the `~/.ssh/config` solution

Answer (score -1):

The normal (i.e. non Windows) operation of  Zero-conf uses the .local "domain".

This is a function of your local network and source computer as Raspberry Pi OS has  Zero-conf enabled by default.

Occasionally caching prevents  Zero-conf resolution and the only cure I have found is to restart all network devices although pinging sometimes refreshes the arp cache.

Try raspberrypi.local

Comment: I ran `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` on my Arch Linux machine but got this error: `Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known`